# Make custom responsive block elements in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making some chevron style links for my web application, and have followed the tutorial here ([breadcrumb links with css](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-flat-style-breadcrumb-links-with-css)) in order to add them to the site. This all works fine. However when I start to shrink the size of the page they rapidly start to pile up on top of each other, and look crap. They remain the same width - whereas I'd like them to gradually shrink in width (and perhaps increase in height to accommodate the contents) as the page size shrinks. Ultimately I'll put in some that point down specifically for the mobile user.

Is it possible to tell bootstrap to shrink a block element or to scale it down as the available page width decreases?

Comment: I can fix this.  I do a lot of responsive layout work.  Make a JSFIDDLE please.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I made the jsfiddle but this works even less well than the code on my page (I copied the html directly from the page source, but for some reason the chevrons aren't even showing up). http://jsfiddle.net/zhtk5zyg/ let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, but maybe give the block this:

```
 height:auto;
```

You only need to find the right class in bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css.
But if you want to edit somthing please use bootstrap.css and not bootstrap.min.css

Comment: OK, thanks. I do all my edits in custom.css (in a Rails app) so I don't get screwed when bootstrap updates.

Comment: Okey, nice, If something is not working in your own css, try to use !important behind something like this: background-color:red !important;

Comment: Thanks. Sadly height:auto didn't get it to behave in the right way. Perhaps I need to style individual div elements into blocks instead.

Comment: No, that takes on the default height of the row by the looks of things. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When ive the code it is easy for me to fix, but on this moment, i dont know haha